# Can I catch a js triggered change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can use jquery to easily catch a change event of a select option when a user clicks it, however if javascript changes the select value, the 'change' event never triggers and needs to be manually triggered.

Is it possible to catch the value changing without manually having to `trigger('change')`?

Example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1fhbha4o/1/

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked, not even to jsFiddle (hence the warning preventing your linking to jsFiddle if nothing is marked as code). Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. If the example is important, put it *in* the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable if relevant. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to trigger the event yourself using `trigger('change')`, or just `change()`. Either is a very common approach to this issue. You could use a `MutationObserver`, but they're not well supported yet and it's probably overkill for this

Comment: Your question is not clear? Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Interesting, never heard of mutationObserver, def not meant for this, but good to know.

Comment: Full content of my question is in the question. The jsfiddle is just an example incase someone like user2181397, is still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to catch the value changing without manually having to `trigger('change')`?

No. No event is fired when JavaScript code sets the value of a select. So your options are:

1. Have a common function you call both in response to a `change` event and also whenever your code changes the value (perhaps centralize changing the value so you don't forget to call it).
2. `.trigger('change')`
3. Polling the value to see if it changes (blech).

Re #1 and #2, you could give yourself a `valWithNotify`:

```
$.fn.valWithNotify = function(arg) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
        return this.val();
    }
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).val(arg).trigger("js-change"); // or just "change", but I'm not a
                                               // fan of synthetic user events
    });
};
```

Comment: *sigh. Thanks, I thought that was the case.